# My program won't paint Here's the code:

Tags: java, paintcomponent

This code won't fill the rectangle.  I tried to extend JComponent but I received an error. How would I extend JComponent?

```
 package com.lewis.GooseEgg;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.swing.JComponent;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class GooseEgg extends Canvas{ //I couldn't extend JComponent
                                       //How would I also extend JComponent
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         g.fillRect(0,0, 100, 100);
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //This is just all the basic stuff I learned                        
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    GooseEgg goose = new GooseEgg();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setTitle("Goose Egg");
    frame.add(goose);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(900, 900);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //The website keeps asking me to add more detail because it says my post is mostly code so I added this. If anyone wants to tutor me at Java
    //I could pay money.
     }

 }
```

Comment: You should add the error message you receive and the location where it appears… "an error" is rather unspecific ;-) Why do you want to extend from both, Canvas and JComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend from `Canvas` and `JComponent`: You should only extend from `JComponent`.

Also you should not do `pack()` and `setSize(…)`. They both set the size of your frame, this does not make sense. Either do `pack()` (in which case you also need to specify a *preferred size* e.g. by overriding [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize--) or setting it with [setPreferredSize(…)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize-java.awt.Dimension-)) or do `setSize(…)`.

Changing `Canvas` to `JComponent` and removing the `pack()` method call seems to produce the correct result.